# What's the Flash equivalent of FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm moving some Flex classes to pure Flash/AS3 to be part of a shared library. I have an event listener on `FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` to create and add display-objects once things are running, but I don't know the right way to do this in Flash?

edit: Maybe if my class subclasses `Sprite` rather than a Flex class, I can add children in the constructor, I don't *need* to wait for a "construction complete" event?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do: When you add children in the constructor, you will not be able to depend on any information about the stage and/or other elements on it.  I have found it a better practice to add an event listener for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE in the constructor, and have the handler method initialize the element.

Answer (score 0):

You're really comparing apples and oranges here.

The Flex Framework is a UI Framework, and the CREATION_COMPLETE event is part of that framework.

Flash Professional is an IDE, primarily geared for creating animation.  It has ActionScript support, but is not a framework and does not offer anything beyond native ActionScript other than libraries or classes you build, buy, create, or borrow.

If you want some parallel to creationComplete, you'll probably need to find--or create--a UI Framework.  It is, in theory, possible (although not easy, nor something I'd recommend) to initialize the Flex Framework for use inside a Flash IDE created movie.  After all, under the hood it is all ActionScript.

Comment: No that's not true. You can create a AS3/Flash project 100% in code using FlashBuilder or FlashDevelop... then all the custom visual components would be based on Sprite rather than UIComponent, etc. `CREATION_COMPLETE` signifies the Flex creation is done... well Flash components have to be created and added to the render-hierarchy too. I think `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` is what I was looking for, roughly.

Comment: @John, what Flextras is saying has some truth I mean it's not apples to oranges, maybe apples to "pear apples", Flex is a set of components all coded up in AS3 or MXML which is compiled into AS3, so what you say has some truth as well but the fact of the matter is Flash itself doesn't have the same life cycle as Flex because of the extra code in UIComponent amongst the rest of the managers, anyhow point is moot I suppose since you've got what you need there I think, creation_complete in the case of Flex is called after the addition of children and layout is complete.

Comment: @John I unclear how your words contradict anything I said; and as such I'm unclear what you think is untrue in my answer.  Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is part of the core classes, and will also be dispatched from a Flex component, or anything that is added to the stage. The stage is "masked" in the context of normal Flex development, but it is still there.  I can accept that ADDED_TO_STAGE may be analogous to CREATION_COMPLETE in some respects.  But, as was stated in another answer, it depends what you want to do.  I'm not sure where ADDED_TO_STAGE will fire in relation to the Flex Lifecycle.

Comment: It should be something that can be found out though - Flex is nothing magic, just extra AS3 libraries. I take your point that things work quite differently but my question was about how to know a parent container is ready for general use, and has a valid internal state.

Comment: @John Nothing in your original question made me think you wanted to know when a parent container is ready for general use and has a valid internal state.  That is a very different interpretation. I see you have edited your question.  My only updated response is that in the context of Flex, you really shouldn't be creating children or adding objects in the creationComplete event; you should be making us of the Flex Comp Lfecycle and doing so w/in createChildren(). In the context of a Sprite, I see no reason not to add children in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

creationComplete Dispatched when the component, and all of its child components, and all of their children, and so on have been created, laid out, and are visible.

See more info on the flex life-cycle events and some that are plain flash here: also +1ed the added_to_stage as it's likely what you'll need in this case.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_3.html